# array index out of bound exception while traversing a hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

I am trying to write a java program to find out the count of words which are occurring twice in the string but I am getting an exception:

> array index out of bound

Input:

2
10
hate love peace love peace hate love peace love peace
8
Tom Jerry Thomas Tom Jerry Courage Tom Courage

Output:

1
2

The complete Code is:

```
class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        while(t>0){
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            int count = 0;
            String str = sc.next();
            String strArray[] = str.split(" ");
            HashMap <String,Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(wordCount.containsKey(strArray[i])){
                    wordCount.put(strArray[i],wordCount.get(strArray[i])+1));
                }
                else{
                     wordCount.put(strArray[i],1);
                }
            }

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordCount.entrySet()) {
                if(entry.getValue()==2)
                    count++;
            }

            System.out.println(count);
            t--;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `sc.next();` returns the next _complete token_ (per their documentation).  A 'token' is one separated by their _delimiter_, which the default matches whitespace.  So you're only getting one word from this; the array is then only one `String` in length, and when you go to `i = 1` in the `for` loop, you end up with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with the logic. Why not get the whole String first and then go for the `split`. This will avoid unnecessary `Scanner` issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String str = sc.next();`

This code is only getting one word, but you intended to get `n` words.

You could just get rid of the array since it is unnecessary, then use:

```
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            String word = sc.next();
            if(wordCount.containsKey(word)){
                wordCount.put(word,wordCount.get(word)+1));
            }
            else{
                 wordCount.put(word,1);
            }
        }
```

However, a more succinct way of writing it would be:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    wordCount.compute(sc.next(), (word,count)-> (count==null)? 1 : count+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
```

Should be:

```
for(int i=0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
```